# WPF hover over with unique images

Tags: wpf, image, mvvm, data-binding

I want to create a Magic the Gathering trading user interface where if a user hover over a specific card name, that it will display that card's image (see image). Currently, in the MultiMasterCardListView, the only image that displays is the Black Lotus card image which I hard-coded that image path. As a result, it does not matter which card name I hover over, it only shows black lotus image.

So I created a property (PlayerCardPath) inside of MultiMasterCardListViewModel, which will loop through all the cards in the database 
and test if the hover over's content/value equals that card name.  If it does then return the path with the card's name and image format. The problem is that mc.Name(from MultiMasterCardViewModel) returns nothing so the "if" statement inside of the foreach doesn't get hit at all.  How do I get the value of whatever is being hover over from the MultiMasterCardListView? Let me know if you need clarification.  Thanks[image]

**MultiMasterCardListView:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="OrderEntrySystem.MultiMasterCardListView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OrderEntrySystem"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="600">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="SharedResources.xaml" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,0,0,5" Height="30">
            <TextBox x:Name="searchTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=SearchText}" Width="100" Height="23" Margin="0,4,5,0" />
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=FilterCommands}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=NestedCommandTemplate}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
                <local:SelectedItemsView />
            </Grid>
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <local:PagingView></local:PagingView>
        </Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SortedCards}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ListViewStyle}">
            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                <Border>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="C:\Users\Teng\Documents\0515-392-team-orange\Team Magic Project\OrderEntrySystem\Images\Black Lotus.JPG"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="175" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Name" Command="{Binding Path=SortCommand}" CommandParameter="Name" />
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Point Value" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PointValue}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

**MultiMasterCardListViewModel:**

```
        public string PlayerCardPath
    {
        get
        {
            string result = null;
            MultiMasterCardListView mC = new MultiMasterCardListView();

            foreach (var card in this.repository.GetMasterCardLists())
            {
                if (card.Name == mC.Name)
                {
                    result = (@"..\..\..\Images\" + mC.Name + ".JPG");
                    break;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

**SharedResources:**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OrderEntrySystem">

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MasterCardListViewModel}">
    <local:MasterCardListView></local:MasterCardListView>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MemberViewModel}">
    <local:MemberView></local:MemberView>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MultiMasterCardListViewModel}">
    <local:MultiMasterCardListView></local:MultiMasterCardListView>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MultiMemberViewModel}">
    <local:MultiMemberView></local:MultiMemberView>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MultiMemberCardListViewModel}">
    <local:MultiMemberCardListView></local:MultiMemberCardListView>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TransactionViewModel}">
    <local:TransactionView></local:TransactionView>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MultiTransactionViewModel}">
    <local:MultiTransactionView></local:MultiTransactionView>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MultiCardTransactionViewModel}">
    <local:MultiCardTransactionView></local:MultiCardTransactionView>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CardConditionViewModel}">
    <local:CardConditionView></local:CardConditionView>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:QuantityViewModel}">
    <local:QuantityView></local:QuantityView>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PurchasePointsViewModel}">
    <local:PurchasePointsView></local:PurchasePointsView>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MultiMyCardListViewModel}">
        <local:MultiMyCardListView></local:MultiMyCardListView>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MultiShoppingCartViewModel}">
    <local:MultiShoppingCartView></local:MultiShoppingCartView>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ShoppingCartViewModel}">
    <local:ShoppingCartView></local:ShoppingCartView>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ReportViewModel}">
    <local:ReportView></local:ReportView>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LoginViewModel}">
    <local:LoginView></local:LoginView>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspacesTemplate">
    <TabControl IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Margin="4" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <TabControl.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="..\..\Images\Magicthegathering-logo.svg.png" Stretch="Uniform" AlignmentY="Bottom" AlignmentX="Center" Opacity="0.5"/>
        </TabControl.Background>
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <Button Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}" Content="X" Cursor="Hand" Margin="4,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" Height="16" Width="16" FontFamily="Courier" FontSize="9" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="NestedCommandTemplate">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Command="{Binding Path=Command}" Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" IsDefault="{Binding Path=IsDefault}" IsCancel="{Binding Path=IsCancel}" Height="23" Width="75" Margin="4,4,0,0" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="CommandsTemplate">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Command="{Binding Path=Command}" Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="HoverOverImage">
    <Border Name="border" BorderThickness="0" 
            Background="Transparent">
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\Teng\Documents\0515-392-team-orange\Team Magic Project\Images\Coalition Honor Guard.JPG" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="HorizontalCommandsTemplate">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Command="{Binding Path=Command}" Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" Height="23" Width="75" Margin="4,4,0,0" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>

<Style x:Key="MainHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Background="{StaticResource Brush_HeaderBackground}" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" Margin="4" Padding="4" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedContentControl}">
                <DockPanel>
                    <ContentPresenter DockPanel.Dock="Top" ContentSource="Header" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" />
                    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ListViewStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ValidationStyleTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}" />
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="true">
                            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding ElementName=customAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}" />
                            <Border Background="Red" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="20" Height="20" CornerRadius="10">
                                <TextBlock Text="!" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" />
                            </Border>
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="customAdorner" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" />
                            </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="PagingButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Webdings" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="23" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="45" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4,0,4,0" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="PagingTextBlock" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4,0,4,0" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

Comment: please post your "images" as `Code`.

Comment: Please post your ListViewStyle markup and class, that is stored in SortedCards collection.

Comment: Ok, it's done per your request.

Comment: "It doesn't work" doesn't help.  You need to debug, see what was requested, see what was returned, and then relay that information in your question.